# Getting 'Use MyMailer.delay.mailer_action(args) to delay sending of emails.' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am getting an odd error: 'Use MyMailer.delay.mailer_action(args) to delay sending of emails.' but I can seem to find out where does it come from:

`app/mailers/user_notifier.rb`

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "test@testing.com"

  def signup_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: t("mailer.signup.subject"))
  end

  ...
end
```

In Console, the non-delayed one works:
`UserNotifier.signup_email(user).deliver`

but when adding delay, error occurs:

```
UserNotifier.signup_email(user).delay.deliver
  Rendered user_notifier/signup_email.html.erb (0.7ms)
RuntimeError: Use MyMailer.delay.mailer_action(args) to delay sending of emails.
    from /Users/quindici/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:20:in `delay'
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/quindici/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/quindici/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/quindici/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

It used to work but was broken sometimes ago. Still didn't get my head around it. Any idea would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it backwards:

```
UserNotifier.signup_email(user).delay.deliver
```

should be

```
UserNotifier.delay.signup_email(user)
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy.clark. So I do not need to call `deliver`? I need deliver as I am trying to get the email object, inject the css to its body then deliver it.

Comment: You should read up on delayed_job it is handling the heavy lifting in your scenario (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-3-mailers). The line I helped correct basically schedules the job with delayed_job. You need to ensure delayed_job is running and processing jobs. You can force the processing of jobs with `rake jobs:work`. 

Basically, delayed job will perform the `.deliver` method for you once the job is picked up and executed.

Answer (score 3):

When you use Delayed_job you'll can access `.dealy` method and then you can put the action mailer method like `.deliver_later` to delay sending of emails.

Simply way to add delayed_job in your project:

1. Add in your Gemfile:

   `gem "delayed_job_active_record"`
   `gem "daemons"`

Create the file "config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb" with:

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 3
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

2. In terminal:

   `$ bin/rails generate delayed_job:active_record`
   `$ bin/rake db:migrate`
   `$ bundle`
   `$ bin/delayed_job start`

Optional to view log: `tail -f log/delayed_job.log`

3. In some Mailer in your project (You can execute this in rails console):

   `SomeMailer.delay.some_method`

Your queue will be processed in 60 seconds. You can remove the property `Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60` to process immediately.

Otherwise, you can configure your application to use delayed_job like your adapter for the active jobs and process works in background. Then you need to put `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job`. This mode always you send an email you don't need to use `.delay`, instead, you call the mailer action and `.deliver_later`, for example: `MyMailer.your_method.deliver_later`. In this mode, the active job will enqueue the email in the delayed_job.

Questions and suggestions are welcome.

Reference: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job